# Ember-CLI: Where is the application route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to install the npm package rails-csrf.  The instructions on the rails-csrf github site say to "add a before model to your application route so your token is fetched automatically."  Where is the application route?

I think it is supposed to be app/routes/application.js but that file does not exist.  Shouldn't that be created by default with the ember new command?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not created by default.

You can use the ember-cli's generator to create one:

```
$ ember generate route application
```

Hope this helps!